# Bootstrap Modal window and Thymeleaf

Tags: view, model, thymeleaf

I have a project with Spring Mvc and I want to use Bootstrap modal windows and Thymeleaf. I hava a view students.jsp witch get list of students from model when I make loop without Thymeleaf everything work ok.
I use JS. But when I use Thymeleaf model windows didn't work ok.

```
    <table class="table table-hover">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Firstname</th>
                <th>Lastname</th>
                <th>Email</th>
                <th></th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
                <tr id="user-${user.id}" th:each="user: ${students}">

                    <td th:text="${user.id}" />
                    <td th:text="${user.firstName}" />
                    <td th:text="${user.lastName}" />
                    <td>
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary editButton"
                            data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal" data-user-id="${user.id}">Edit</button>
                    </td>
                </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $("#myModal").on('show.bs.modal', function(e) {
            var userId = $(e.relatedTarget).data('user-id');

            var cols = $('#user-' + userId + ' td');
            var firstName = $(cols[0]).text();
            var lastName = $(cols[1]).text();
            var email = $(cols[2]).text();

            $('#firstNameInput').val(firstName);
            $('#lastNameInput').val(lastName);
            $('#emailInput').val(email);
        });

        $("#myModal").on('hidden.bs.modal', function() {
            var form = $(this).find('form');
            form[0].reset();
        });
    </script>
```

It doesn't get data from list. I don't know how to solve this problem. Please help me :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a small problem with `data-user-id` attribute in your "Edit" button.

Instead of:

```
data-user-id="${user.id}"
```

...you should have:

```
th:data-user-id="${user.id}"
```

...so that the attribute is processed by Thymeleaf and `${user.id}` actually replaced with expected value.

Answer (score 0):

```
<tr th:each="user: ${students}" th:id="'user-' + ${user.id}">
                <td th:text="${user.id}" />
                <td th:text="${user.firstName}" />
                <td th:text="${user.lastName}" />
                <td th:text="${user.email}" />
                <td>
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary editButton"
                        data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal"
                        th:data-user-id="${user.id}">Edit</button>
                </td>
            </tr>
```